# Attempting to find a probability of a certain roll.

Tags: probability

I have a problem where I have 7 semi-random values, each $9 \le x \le 18$ and $\sum x_i=95$.  It is convenient to think about them as 9 rolls of a 2 sided dice with the faces being 1 or 2, but this doesn't quite correctly model the situation (there are variable modifiers).

I originally tried to model this by tracking the values individually and approximating it by an independent event probability by tracking the frequency of each value, but since the individual values are not independent it seriously underestimates the number of events required to observe a success.  Subsequent rolls are independent, however.

So ... for the basic problem there are $10^7$ possible tuples of 7 members which I can track in order to find a distribution of the rolls and then use that to form an independent event probability.

1 - How can I reduce the number of states from $10^7$ correctly, knowing that the sum is 95 eliminates a tremendous amount of the higher valued states?  Even knowing the correct total number of states is helpful.

2 - Is there a useful form that would help me say what the probability of a certain grouping of results is?  (For example $x_1 \gt 16$)

Comment: Take a look at this. [Partition (number theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question was how many solutions to $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{7} x_i = 95$ with each $ x_i \ge 9$ then it would become more simple: it would be the same as the number of solutions to  $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{7} y_i = 95-7\times 8 = 39$ with each with $y_i \ge 1$.  This is well known and can be solved using "stars and bars": it is ${39-1 \choose 7-1} = 2760681.$

Your additional constraint that each $x_i \le 18$ makes the calculation a little more complicated, but my [Java applet](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm) will calculate it using recursion if you ask for compositions of $39$ with exactly $7$ terms each no more than $10$.  The answer is $512365$.

It may be fastest to actually take all $10^7$ possibilities and and reject the almost 95% of them which do not sum to the correct amount, especially if programming time is taken into account.

You asked about further restrictions: the number with $x_1 = 17$ is the same as the number of compositions of $30$ with exactly $6$ terms each no more than $10$, while the number with $x_1 = 18$ is the same as the number of compositions of $29$ with exactly $6$ terms each no more than $10$, meaning that the number with $x_1 \gt 16$ is $50877+47712 = 98589$.

If you are using something like your "9 rolls of a 2 sided dice with the faces being 1 or 2" then the various compositions will not be equally probable.